# New column based on pattern in column names

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, data.table

I have a data table. I want to create a new column equal to a function of the values in those columns with a pattern in the column name

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(Client = LETTERS[1:5], 
   Apple_2012 = rpois(5,5),  Apple_2013 = rpois(5,5), Pear_2012 = rpois(5,5), 
   Pear_2013 = rpois(5,5), Orange_2012 = rpois(5,5), Orange_2013 = rpois(5,5))
```

For example, I'd like

```
DT <- DT[ ,Fruit_2012 := Apple_2012 + Pear_2012 + Orange_2012]
```

But I'd like to do this by recognizing the "2012" pattern. Something like this:

```
DT <- DT[ ,Fruit_2012 := sum(names(DT)[grep("2012", names(DT))]) ]
```

Or

```
DT <- DT %.%
  mutate(Fruit_2012 = sum(names(DT)[grep("2012", names(DT))]) )
```

But neither of these approaches bear any fruit.

```
# Error in sum(names(DT)[grep("2012", names(DT))]) : 
#  invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

I've tried playing around with combinations of `list`, `quote`, and `with=FALSE`, but with no more luck.

Comment: Maybe: `DT[, Fruit_2012 := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols=grep("2012$", names(DT))]`?

Comment: Great for `sum`. But would like to use a general function that can accept a vector argument (like `max`). Should I use `apply(.SD, 1, FUN)`? It works, but is there a more idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  Client = LETTERS[1:5], 
  Apple_2012 = rpois(5,5),
  Apple_2013 = rpois(5,5), 
  Pear_2012 = rpois(5,5), 
  Pear_2013 = rpois(5,5), 
  Orange_2012 = rpois(5,5), 
  Orange_2013 = rpois(5,5)
)
```

Given this data, I'd highly recommend that you turn it into [tidy
form](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html), because it puts
variables on a consistent footing:

```
library(reshape2)

dfm <- melt(df, id = "Client")

variables <- colsplit(dfm$variable, "_", c("fruit", "year"))
dfm$variable <- NULL
dfm$fruit <- variables$fruit
dfm$year <- as.numeric(variables$year)

head(dfm)
#>   Client value fruit year
#> 1      A     4 Apple 2012
#> 2      B     4 Apple 2012
#> 3      C     5 Apple 2012
#> 4      D     8 Apple 2012
#> 5      E     3 Apple 2012
#> 6      A     8 Apple 2013
```

Then it's easy to summarise the way you want with dplyr, or otherwise,:

```
library(dplyr)

dfm %.% group_by(Client, year) %.% summarise(fruit = mean(value))
#> Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
#> Groups: Client
#> 
#>    Client year fruit
#> 1       A 2012 5.333
#> 2       A 2013 5.667
#> 3       B 2012 3.333
#> 4       B 2013 5.333
#> 5       C 2012 5.667
#> 6       C 2013 7.000
#> 7       D 2012 5.000
#> 8       D 2013 6.000
#> 9       E 2012 4.667
#> 10      E 2013 4.333
```

Comment: +1 I appreciate this is a bit of an XY question in the specific case I've used, but I'm still curious about solutions for the general problem.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `Reduce` in these cases:

```
DT[, Fruit_2012 := Reduce('+', .SD), .SDcols = grep("2012", names(DT))]

#or
DT[, Fruit_2012_max := Reduce(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = grep("2012", names(DT))]
```

Answer (score 0):

try contains in select function.

```
 mutate(DT,fruits2012 = rowSums(DT %.% select(contains("2012"))))
```

it is a little ugly. but it works.

I wish there is a .SD in dplyr package. if so, the code would be like this:

```
DT %.%
      select(contains("2012")) %.%
      mutate(fruits2012 = rowSums(.SD))
```